# WebAPI upload called twice, error response

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a controller that takes a file uploaded, processes it, and then responds to the server.  Everything works perfect locally.  Everything works perfect when deployed to the server if the test file is small.  However, once I try a larger test file (27MB), I get some strange results.  After processing and what appears to be sending the OK back (which takes about 90 seconds), the whole request starts processing again.   My client is NOT sending a new request, and the IIS logs show ONLY one request coming in.    My code is simplified to the following:

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadNfsExcelFile()
  {
     // Using this STRICTLY to make sure the request is new each time for logging and debugging
     Guid trackMe=Guid.NewGuid();
     Logger.DebugFormat("Request coming in: {0}", trackMe);
     string tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
     // This handles the persistence of the file name for processing
     CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(tempPath);
     await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider);
     foreach (string result in streamProvider.FileData.Select(entry => entry.LocalFileName))
     {
          /*  File processing here */
     }
     Logger.DebugFormat("File processing done: {0}", trackMe);
     return Ok(new 
     {  
         token: "This would be the response token"
     });
  }
```

My log file shows the "Request coming in: GUID" log statement, followed by the "File Processing done: GUID" statement, then immediately show the logging I have i place for the some filters (authentication validation) followed by the set of "Request coming in: NEWGUID", "File Processing Done: NEWGUID".  At this point, Chrome shows an empty response.  My IIS logs show ONLY one request with a response status of **200**

**EDIT**

Additional information.  Still getting this issue, it seems to be when the file processing takes more than 60 seconds the serer just reprocesses the request.

**EDIT 2**
Checking on wireshark now locally, it seems my TCP is resending the request (I'm getting "[TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]" every 60 seconds that corresponds to the re-execution of the web api method

Comment: Have you debugged the client to see where this extra request is coming from?

Comment: It doesn't happen locally and I cannot currently attach debugger to server where it does occur